# How do I reset qml-properties to their default value?

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I have a `TextField` where I want to conditionally show or hide the background. Here's a text field with a background:

```
TextField {
    id: with_background
}
```

and here's one without:

```
TextField {
    id: without_background
    background: null
}
```

I've tried setting the background conditionally to `undefined`, but that didn't work:

```
TextField {
    background: row.activeFocus ? TextField.background : null;
}
```

Is this even possible in QML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TextField` takes ownership of the background. When you set the background to `null`, the old background is destroyed to avoid backgrounds "piling up". Therefore you cannot toggle the background back and forth. However, if all you need is to toggle its visibility, you can do:

```
TextField {
    background.visible: row.activeFocus
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This seems logical in retrospective. I just haven't completely understood QML yet.